# How to get svn revision previous to specified?

Tags: svn, version-control, svnkit

I need to automate some task.
And I need to find svn revision previous to specified revision for specified URL.
How to do it using `svn` tool and how to do it in `svnkit`?

For example I have following history:

```
D:\wc\trunk>svn log svn://localhost/pg/trunk -q
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r99 | user | 2016-01-27 16:29:11 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r98 | user | 2016-01-27 16:28:59 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r90 | user | 2016-01-27 16:28:48 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r86 | user | 2016-01-27 16:28:35 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r85 | user | 2016-01-27 16:28:24 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r62 | user | 2016-01-26 18:04:47 +0200 (Tue, 26 Jan 2016)
```

Verbose output:

```
D:\wc\trunk>svn log svn://localhost/pg/trunk -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r99 | user | 2016-01-27 16:29:11 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/f1.txt

Change 4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r98 | user | 2016-01-27 16:28:59 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/f1.txt

Change 3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r90 | user | 2016-01-27 16:28:48 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/f1.txt

Change 2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r86 | user | 2016-01-27 16:28:35 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/f1.txt

Change 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r85 | user | 2016-01-27 16:28:24 +0200 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/f1.txt

Init revision
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r62 | user | 2016-01-26 18:04:47 +0200 (Tue, 26 Jan 2016) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /trunk

1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to know what revision is before revision 90.
How to get that previous revision?

Comment: Do you mean you need just the revisions in which the URL was modified?  Otherwise the answer is 1-(_n_-1)

Comment: I have some URL(svn://localhost/pg/test) and some revision(77). I need to execute some command to get previous revision for that specified revision and URL. Something like "svn svn://localhost/pg/test -r 1:77 --limit 2". But "--limit=2" returns first two revisions, not last two revisions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question now.  Revisions 87, 88, and 89 didn't modify anything under `trunk`, so you'll have to go up a level to `pg`.  What are you trying to get from this "missing" revision?

Comment: I added verbose output. I just need to find the revision previous for 90.

Comment: The verbose output didn't help.  Do you mean you want to get 86 or 89?  What's special about 90?  It looks like every other revision.

Comment: It is just an example. I have some svn URL. Also I have some revision. I need to find out the revision previous for specified.

Answer (score 2):

Swapping the order of the revisions given to the `-r` switch will reverse the search order.  From the SVN repository, this will show the two earliest revisions in the given range (1700000 to HEAD):

```
> svn log --limit=2 -r1700000:HEAD -q http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1700035 | kotkov | 2015-08-29 10:16:13 -0400 (Sat, 29 Aug 2015)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1700130 | rhuijben | 2015-08-30 12:02:56 -0400 (Sun, 30 Aug 2015)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this will show the two latest:

```
> svn log --limit=2 -rHEAD:1700000 -q http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1727040 | philip | 2016-01-27 08:23:08 -0500 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1727028 | stefan2 | 2016-01-27 08:02:24 -0500 (Wed, 27 Jan 2016)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not an SVNKit user myself, but I'd imagine it supports this as well.